# Docker machine not reload when code has change

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to use docker-machine to develop my project. But I have problem when develop use docker-machine, I must rebuild my container for every change my code to see the change. My question is how the right way to use docker-machine for development or better to not use docker-machine.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
        - "8000"
    volumes:
        - ./web:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
        - .env
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 app:app

nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./web:/usr/src/app
    links:
        - web:web

data:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: "true"

postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}

volumes:
    db-data:
```

This my application structure:

```
.
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- nginx
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- nginx.conf
|   `-- ujicoba04.conf
|-- README.md
`-- web
    |-- app.py
    |-- config.py
    |-- Dockerfile
    |-- __pycache__
    |   |-- app.cpython-37.pyc
    |   `-- config.cpython-37.pyc
    |-- requirements.txt
    |-- static
    `-- templates
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: What's this got to do with Python? :) Correction: How's this a Python issue/bug? Seems more like it's related purely to docker and the way it pushes content in a container?

Comment: I use python in my project.

Comment: That's all fine, but how's this a Python coding issue? The tags are meant to be related to the issue you have. Not the tech stack you use. So if this issue isn't related to Python, I'd be happy to remove the tag for you unless you want to do it yourself or clarify details why the tag is there :)

Comment: oh, ok. I will remove python tag. thanks to remind me.

Comment: Np, as to your issue. The easiest (and perhaps dirtiest way) would be to built in SSH and enable SSH from the start, and simply use SSHFS or something to remote-change the code until you have a working code base. Then re-deploying it is probably the only real way of making sure everything works :)